# Change request url for static resource with angular2+

Tags: angular, static, resources, interceptor

Is there a way with angular2+ to change the url of all static resource requests (for example an image src in DOM)? The goal is to change the url of a resource from "assets/images/image.jpg" to "/app-name/assets/images/image.jpg".
I have found httpInterceptors but it works only with api requests.

Comment: You could create a pipe

Comment: Yes but with a pipe i have to change all existing resource urls (also for third party components like themes). I'm searching a way to do this without change urls in html templates...

Comment: Otherwise a server-side redirection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use base `<base href="/antpath/">` in your index.html

then the value in href (/antpath/) will be appended to all your request.